# pycharm/black screen on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I just started using Ubuntu a few days ago and I'm trying to follow a tutorial to learn about it. today, I was trying to install **Pycharm** on ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 but I got a **black screen** (attached)
I'm using a VMware btw.
I tried to google the issue but apparently, this issue is not common so I'm kindly seeking your help.

Regards,
[image: error-screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Disable 3D acceleration in VirtualBox machine display settings, that's all. For VMware, I guess, solution is similar.